# Get ID of Last Entery in MSSQL Server via PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, sqlsrv

Hello i need a little Help.

I have a MSSQL Server and i need the ID of the Last Entery.

My PHP Code is:

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

$sqlnextid = "Select IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Person')";
echo $sqlnextid;
$nextid = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sqlnextid );
echo $nextid;
```

Unfortunately `$nextid` only returns `"Resource id#3"` and not the correct `ID` in the SQL Management Studio. The sql query `"Select IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Person')"` works fine an give the correct answer - (33).

[image: sqlquery in sql studio]

Where is my mistake? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sqlnextid )` does not do what you think it does. You are getting a query result, you need to iterate over this to get each row, see `sqlsrv_fetch_array` for more examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch the data from the executed query uisng `sqlsrv_fetch_array()`. As is explained in the documentation, the function `sqlsrv_query()` [returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-query?view=sql-server-ver15#return-value) a statement resource or `false` if the statement cannot be created and/or executed.

As a side note, always check the result from the `sqlsrv_connect()` and `sqlsrv_query()` calls.

```
<?php

...
// Connection
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

// Query
$sqlnextid = "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Person') AS [CurrentIdent]";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sqlnextid );
if( $stmt === false ) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

// Data
$ident = 0;
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $ident = $row["CurrentIdent"];
}
echo $ident;
...

?>
```

Comment: Thanks :) I didn't look at the ms docu this is very nice to have.

Answer (score 0):

`sqlsrv_query` [returns returns a statement resource on success and FALSE if an error occurred](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php).

You can access the result using `sqlsrv_fetch_object`.

```
$sqlnextid = "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Person') AS LastId"
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlnextid);
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_object($result)
echo $row->LastId;
```